# Upper memory limit apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2, memory

I have a big php script that needs a gigabyte or more to run. I set the memory_limit in php.ini to 2048M. If I echo the limit with ini_get, I get the 2048M as expected. But when I run the script it fails and says that it could only allocate 512mb. I have 16GB of ram on the server, so its not that. There must be another limit set somewhere..?

Comment: what is output of ulimit -v

Answer (score 1):

PHP, Webserver processes are also limited by the per process max memory limit. You'll have to ask an administrator to change the limit in this case. On linux/unix, you can check the limit with the following command in the shell:

```
ulimit -a
```

or use PHP to check:

```
<?php print system('ulimit -a'); ?>
```

Comment: This is what i get:
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 6144
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 266
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

Comment: Hi, try RLimitMEM in your httpd.conf to set memory limit of Apache children processes. This guy seems to have the same problem of yours http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-206304.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about any apache limits but I do know Linux supports setting resource limits for processes. Can't remember the exact details but one command involved is ulimit.